# System.DmlException:INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, visual-workflow

I have a flow and aura in which I will insert first items into cart and then to Order in my scenario for community portal and sys admin its working fine. But when I test it with Custom Profile user products are not getting added, I checked dubug log I got above error on custom object Cart. I have give all permissions to that object for respective profile. I am not able to get what I am missing. Can anyone Please help with this. You can find respective screenshots below.
[image: error in debug log]
[image: Profile permission]

[image: Controller code]

Comment: This error is all about sharing, rather than permissions. A referenced record is not readable by the user.

Comment: The error could be because community user may not have access to product2 or account record.

Comment: As @PhilW said, check the sharing setting, it might be `private` and based on the user role or group or criteria et,  might only have read access to that.

Answer (score 0):

The INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY exception caused if the user profile does not have the permission to execute the DML statements. Here in you scenarion you have the permission of Carts custom object. You can check Permission for other related Parent Objects like Account, Product etc.

As a workaround you can change the sharing access of the class into "without sharing" to check if the insertLineItem method execute or not.

Note: This is not the Best Practice if you want to move this code to production level.